# Get facebook age_range using node.js https.get()

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am currently using the following to get basic user info from facebook using a token.

```
  var options = {
  host: 'graph.facebook.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/me/?access_token=' + token
};
https.get(options, function(result) {
  var fbResponse = '';
  result.on('data', function(chunk) {
    fbResponse = JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log(fbResponse.error.type);
  }
```

How can I get the age_range field? It is one of the default provided information that doesn't require any additional permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly tell the API that you need `age_range`. You can do this by specifying it in the `fields` parameter. For example:

```
/me?fields=age_range&access_token={token}
```

This should return something like:

```
{
   "age_range": {
      "min": 21
   },
   "id": <user_id>
}
```